# In Android Is there a configuration file somewhere where I can manipulate those properties that are visible in the "Settings" app?

Tags: android, configuration, settings, configuration-files

In Android Is there a configuration file somewhere where I can manipulate those properties that are visible in the system "Settings" app?

Or how can I (maybe programmatically or via a script or whichever way) manipulate the values found in system "Settings" app?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this myself in another thread here:
[Is it safe to edit settings.db in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978385/is-it-safe-to-edit-settings-db-in-android)

Basically, there is not a configuration file as such, but the settings are stored in an sqlite database in this directory:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

You can use an sqlite browser to view and modify the values in there. The database is then exposed to the Android operating system through a settings-ContentProvider. As I have noted however, sometimes there is a mismatch between settings found in the settings app and in the database. This is probably because (of a bug) the settings app caches these settings locally. It is the settings exposed through the ContentProvider that are used by the system though as I have tested here.